# Como fazer um event Change em ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Em **ASP.NET** temos o *Event Change* direto no `Code Be-hind`

```
 protected void ddlCiclo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //algo aqui
    }
```

Qual seria o equivalente em **ASP.NET Core MVC** para um `DropDownList`?

Comment: Creio que a melhor maneira é adicionar um listener ao evento ```change``` do select, via Javascript, e fazer uma chamada AJAX, ou então dar um submit no form

Comment: Não existe um equivalente em MVC. Não existe code behind nem postback. O que você faz é capturar o evento JS [change](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) do elemento HTML associado e fazer uma chamada GET (ou PUT) ao controler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É difícil comparar dois paradigmas tão diferentes: Web Forms x MVC.

Somente para ilustrar, veja o fluxo de tratamento de um evento no ASP.NET WebForms e no ASP.NET MVC:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fonte da imagem: [Slide share: Mvc presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/MaslowB/mvc-presentation-13786492)

No seu caso específico, você que tratar o evento da modifição de um valor em uma lista suspensa.

A interface visual do ASP.NET MVC é composta de HTML + Javascript + CSS (lembando que MVC é um padrão de arquitetura que pode ser aplicado fora do escopo WEB)

No caso de uma lista suspensa, você pode fazer assim:
Imagine que você precise uma lista com os ANO de nascimento do usuário, e na seleção você precise fazer algo
1 - Primeiro você precisa de um modelo (o M do MVC)

```
public class AnosModel
{
    public string anoNasc{get;set;}

    public List<SelectListItem> listaAnos() // simular um repositório. Eu sei que isso deveria estar em outra camada, mas por motivos de simplificação eu coloquei aqui.
    {
       List<SelectListItem> anos= new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "1970", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "1971", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "1972", Value = "3" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "1973", Value = "4" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "1974", Value = "5" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "1975", Value = "6" }

        };
        return anos;
    }
 }
```

2 - Criamos a View (O V do MVC. Neste exemplo vou omitir a criação completa da view e focar na construção da lista suspensa)

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AnoNasc,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Anos, 
        new { onchange = "modificado(@Model.AnosNasc)" })

<script>
    function modificado(ano) {
        // fazer algo aqui. Você pode inclusive fazer uma chamada ao controller usando um dos verbos REST (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc..)
        if (ano<"1974") {
          alert("Você é velho!");
       }
       else
       {
         alert("Você é jovem!");
       }
    }
</script>
```

3 - E o controller (o C do MVC)

```
 public ActionResult Formulario1()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> anos = listaAnos();
        ViewBag.Anos = anos;// a passgem da lista é feita por ViewBag
        AnosModel modelo=new AnosModel();
        return View(modelo);
    }
```

Este é um cenário bem simplificado, mas que serve para ilustrar a diferença dos paradigmas